# Allow pfSense to route from WAN to LAN

Tags: networking, routing, pfsense

I have a pfSense instance with two network interfaces set up between a LAN and WAN:

```
192.168.1.0/24 (WAN) <-> (192.168.1.100) pfSense (10.0.1.100) <-> 10.0.1.1/24(LAN)
```

For simplicity, I have allowed all traffic in the filtering rules.

This works fine and a machine on the LAN with pfSense (10.0.1.100) as the gateway can connect to hosts on the WAN:

```
<10.0.1.5> $ ping 192.168.1.10
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=11.753 ms
```

However, a machine on the WAN with pfSense (now 192.168.1.100) as the gateway can not connect to hosts on the LAN:

```
<192.168.1.10> $ ping 10.0.1.5
*timeout*
```

The firewall rules allow all traffic in both directions.

tcpdump shows that the packets arrive on the WAN interface correctly but are never sent on the LAN interface.

Is there a function of pfSense that prohibits routing from WAN to LAN? What must be done to allow machines in WAN to route to LAN.

*I am aware of the security implications. This is a simplified example.*

Comment: Are you using NAT?

Comment: Yes I am. NAT is enabled for a number of forwarding rules.

Comment: NAT is your problem. Unless you are using one-to-one NAT, you are going to need to originate traffic from one side only. Even with one-to-one NAT, you will need to ping from the outside using the translated address.

Comment: That makes sense. If you put the content of your comment into an answer, I will up vote and accept it.

Comment: I created the answer from the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAT is your problem. Unless you are using one-to-one NAT, you are going to need to originate traffic from one side only. Even with one-to-one NAT, you will need to ping from the outside using the translated address.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a couple years old now, but there is a solution.

NAT is the problem, but in PFSense Outbound NAT you can change the Mode to Hybrid then enter a static rule along the lines of:
WAN interface, source 10.0.1.0/24 destination 192.168.1.0/24, and check the Do Not NAT option.
This will prevent NAT from occurring on traffic going from the local network to this specific external network. 
You also need a rule in the firewall rules allowing the WAN network to access the LAN network.